# Asynchronous Function In NextAuth Completing Before Value Returned

Tags: reactjs, firebase, asynchronous, next.js, next-auth

On signin, I'm attempting to query FirestoreDB and then return the user data or null.

I'm trying to do this with async await, but the dependent code runs before the db query has been completed. This can be seen when "CORRECT," (right credentials) is console logged after the empty user details (not complete).

Thanks,

This is my code:

```
let data = await db.collection('users').where("email", "==", email).get().then(querySnapshot => {
                console.log("SOMETHING")
                let arr = []
                querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => arr.push(doc.data()))
                console.log(arr)
                // console.log(sc.decrypt(arr[0].password))
                
                if (arr[0].email == email) {
                    bcrypt.compare(password, arr[0].password, (err, match) => {
                        

                       if (match) {
                            console.log("CORRECT")

                            return arr[0]
                       } else {
                           if (err) {
                            console.log(err)
                           
                        }
                            console.log("INCORRECT")

                            return null
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
            
                
            console.log("DATA " +  data)
                return data ? data : null
```

Answer (score 0):

An hour of searching, but 2 minutes after I post I figure it out.

Here is the working code for anyone in the same boat:

```
let data = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                db.collection('users').where("email", "==", email).get().then(querySnapshot => {
                    console.log("SOMETHING")
                    let arr = []
                    querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => arr.push(doc.data()))
                    console.log(arr)
                    // console.log(sc.decrypt(arr[0].password))
                    
                    if (arr[0].email == email) {
                        bcrypt.compare(password, arr[0].password, (err, match) => {
                            
    
                           if (match) {
                                console.log("CORRECT")
    
                                resolve(arr[0])
                           } else {
                               if (err) {
                                console.log(err)
                               
                            }
                                console.log("INCORRECT")
    
                                resolve(null)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            })

            
            
                
            
            Promise.all([data]).then(async () => {
                
                console.log(await data)
            })
            
            return data ? data : null
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).